why I am not getting the value of variable in query
I am fetching the variable from url when I print them it shows excellent output in console
mgr = request.args.get('mgr')  # Getting the value of 'mgr' parameter from the query string
dept = request.args.get('dept')  # Getting the value of 'dept' parameter from the query string
    
print("Manager",mgr)
print("Department:", dept)

but when I fire these variables in query it shows following output
employee_data = EmployeeBio.query.filter(EmployeeBio.department == dept, func.lower(EmployeeBio.line_manager).ilike(f'%{mgr.lower()}%')).all()

output query
SELECT employee_bio.employee_id AS employee_bio_employee_id, employee_bio.name AS employee_bio_name, employee_bio.designation AS employee_bio_designation, employee_bio.department AS employee_bio_department, employee_bio.years_in_usf AS employee_bio_years_in_usf, employee_bio.is_manager AS employee_bio_is_manager, employee_bio.line_manager AS employee_bio_line_manager, employee_bio.is_cxo AS employee_bio_is_cxo, employee_bio.cxo AS employee_bio_cxo
FROM employee_bio
WHERE employee_bio.department = %(department_1)s AND lower(employee_bio.line_manager) ILIKE %(lower_1)s

why this %(department_1)s instead of value in dept variable?

%(department_1)s etc are placeholders for parameter values. The actual values are (usually - it depends on the db driver) passed separately to the database, whcih constructs the final query.

Does this answer your question? SQLAlchemy: print the actual query

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
